# php unset keys from array which keys match with preg_match fucntion

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am storing users login details on `$_SESSION` and now I am trying to remove only session which key starts with `fb_`(this is facebook session data).

### Getting this array output:

```
Array
(
    [sproperty] => for sale
    [scommercial] => 0
    [previousURL] => http://192.168.1.233/propio/public/assets/img/progress.gif
    [fb_681840795262337_code] => AQDktd4q_QhpGKAYVyf6eKLtuWvwsc7c8ssXzmA0abvT4XhvAjy2ySTk969-HXSTyCNO0pWY0utwDixxBOpF6n6-YMrKed0wr2c3lBReY85CgH7rg06hqTHeJnv04uextP48m2v7D1se32ogqIfxbtsbmI8eX8xkoLugjCTljKwdCS9GYGkPCjOQyePoS_b62fV9Wfz7BH_70EAW2Y9TjjbmIyXYyTYBkhWQ9cUH9vGMYV9wnPda_v0jxQnb3p043qGQ4bT3DEb82Qohkvs_ktt1vepIf_859DrMgWKfT7B5WyDM9fFk4Azp_SfJc6_mjaoCcdIUmncQGNePJYS7-0lN
    [fb_681840795262337_access_token] => CAAJsIW5lHYEBAKa7YSrgokZC9lS2ZCFBeRLzD5VhTONIJeG1hkPU1wfRAZAaIf29ofBtldeFeteZAs2z3Mz3nRCoJsw3AuZCZBEHWAnBrsZCV5crMgjUjebmTP3FzoOEG0o02u4bopI8OJgY3kKCXU5bTeeKfPQ6kNAyStl8ehlZCOIhcQgkZAIOfvoNTk62N5wsfZCxsswlPt7EX0IoZA0Gkd2
    [fb_681840795262337_user_id] => 1375895206037186
    [success] => Login successfully
)
```

I have created bellow function and it will call only when user click on `logout` button.

```
public function logout(){

    // Unset facebook session data
    $readSession = $_SESSION;
    foreach($readSession as $key => $value) {
      if(preg_match('/fb_(.*)/s', $key)) {
        unset($readSession[$key]);
      }
    }

}
```

In this function I have wrote `unset code` to clear facebook keys (name starts with `fb_`) but unset is not working from my array. I am still getting all keys from array.

Any Idea. Why it is not working or What I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: If you print `$_SESSION` it's clear, why it doesn't get unset, because you unset it in: `$readSession`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are not directly modifying the `$_SESSION` array. Instead, you are only changing the copy you created. Just unset the variable from the `$_SESSION` for it to be properly removed.

```
public function logout(){

    // Unset facebook session data
    foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
      if(preg_match('/fb_(.*)/s', $key)) {
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
      }
    }

}
```

Also, you don't need regex for this. Just use [`strpos`](https://secure.php.net/strpos) for the same result. Plus, this works even better than the regular expression for finding `'fb_'` at the start of the string since [as Rizier123 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31159086/php-unset-keys-from-array-which-keys-match-with-preg-match-fucntion#comment50327112_31159217) you forgot a start of string anchor (`^`).

```
public function logout(){

    // Unset facebook session data
    foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
      if(strpos($key, 'fb_') === 0) {
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: We are already there since 6 minutes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31159086/php-unset-keys-from-array-which-keys-match-with-preg-match-fucntion#comment50326829_31159086 (Also to make the regex works correct, OP also would have to add the anchor `^` to match from the start)

Comment: @Rizier123 I'm on mobile, so I couldn't see comments while writing my answer, but you are correct, you were first. As for the regex, that is true as well.

Comment: @Mr.Happy wow, do you even read the comments under your question? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31159086/php-unset-keys-from-array-which-keys-match-with-preg-match-fucntion#comment50326829_31159086